# add root elements in xml using XmlDocument C#

Tags: c#, xml

I want to add a root elements --testsuites into my existing xml report.
My current report looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <testsuite name="classname" tests="9" failures="3" errors="6" time="2919" 
  disabled="0" skipped="0">
  <testcase name="Setup1" time="5" classname="classname">
  </testcase>
  <testcase name="Setup2" time="49" classname="classname>
  </testcase>
  <testcase name="Setup23" time="357" classname="classname">
  </testcase>
  </testsuite>
```

I want it change to

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <testsuites>
     <testsuite name="classname" tests="9" failures="3" errors="6" time="2919" disabled="0" skipped="0">
      <testcase name="Setup1" time="5" classname="classname">
      </testcase>
      <testcase name="Setup2" time="49" classname="classname">
      </testcase>
      <testcase name="Setup23" time="357" classname="classname">
      </testcase>
     </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
```

My current doesn't work on me

```
XmlDocument report = new XmlDocument();
report.Load(fileOfReport);
XmlElement root = report.CreateElement("root");
root.SetAttribute("testsuites","testsuites");
XmlElement child = report.CreateElement("child");
child.GetElementsByTagName("testsuite");
report.DocumentElement.AppendChild(root);
root.AppendChild(child);        
report.Save(fileOfReport);
```

Is there anyone can help?

Comment: Please don't copy XML source code from Internet Explorer. Copy XML source code from the XML files you are handling.

Comment: I am new to XML area. Can you explain more on this? Are you saying i should convert the xml source code to a file?

Comment: No, I am saying you should not copy and paste the interactive preview that Internet Explorer displays when you open XML files with it. That's useless because it contains extra characters. Open the XML file in a text editor.

Comment: @JiangJiali Don't include `+` and `-`. People have to remove that stuff *by hand* before the XML will parse. It's inconsiderate to expect them to do that for you.

Comment: thanks everyone, i change it now. please help on how to add the root element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the CreateElement to create the node and append the required childs . Finally append the Newly created node to the Document .

```
 XmlDocument report = new XmlDocument();
    report.Load(fileOfReport);
    XmlElement root = report.CreateElement("testsuites");           
    var items = report.GetElementsByTagName("testsuite");
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
    {
        root.AppendChild(items[i]);
    }
    report.AppendChild(root);
    report.SaveAs(fileOfReport);
```

Comment: Thanks, Gowri. This works for me only after change the last line to save instead of load.